# Alternative to WebMvcBasePathAndHostnameTransformationFilter in springdoc 2 , OpenAPI 3, spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springfox, springdoc

I am trying to migrate from springboot 2 to 3. As springfox has not been updated as per Jakarta EE specifications followed in springboot 3, we cannot use springfox with SB3. I am trying to use springdoc 2 instead. But unable to find an alternative to WebMvcBasePathAndHostnameTransformationFilter which was used earlier for the below requirement.
My requirement is to access swagger APIs over API Gateway i.e. override the hostname in the v2/api-docs response for it to be rendered.
Please suggest some alternative method for the same using springdoc.

I tried using SwaggerIndexTransformer but was not really able to implement the same feature.